# Irreversible State Change

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

When we have irreversible state change than at every point during that change it is said that pressure inside a system is not determined or known and because of that it is impossible to represent irreversible processes in
P-V diagram as far as I know. Why is internal pressure not determined during irreversible process at any volume system has during state change? What does it mean that system has non defined pressure?

Answer (score 1):

An ideal gas satisfies the ideal gas law only under thermodynamic equilibrium conditions.  In an irreversible expansion or compression, the gas is not at thermodynamic equilibrium except in the initial and final states.  So the force per unit area exerted by the gas on the piston cannot be determined using the ideal gas law.  For an irreversible expansion or compression, the force per unit area on the piston depends not just on the gas volume, but also on the rate of change of volume.  So what are you supposed to use to determine the amount of work done by the gas?  Your only alternative is to impose the force per unit area by external means.

Comment: Ohh, yes thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have a piston with some gas, and you very quickly push in the piston.

The typical momentum of atoms near the wall of the piston that did not move, will be essentially the same as the momentum before the piston was compressed.

However, the momentum of atoms that have interacted with the piston will have increased because of the compression.

Since the system is not in equilibrium, it is not possible to assign the system a single pressure describing the average momentum of particles in piston.

However, you can still define a stress tensor by averaging momenta in small volumes of the gas, and and talk about the flow of momentum locally in the system. To the extent that in a small region the system may be close to equilibrium over a shorter time scale than the whole system, you could use the stress tensor to define pressure gradients induced by the change in volume. The pressure gradients would tend to decrease over time as the gas reaches a new equilibrium state.

Answer (score 0):

> ..and because of that it is impossible to represent irreversible
> processes in P-V diagram as far as I know.

You can represent a reversible or irreversible process with a $PV$ diagram.

$P$ on a $PV$ diagram always represents the external pressure. Only if you are told the process(es) is  reversible, can you say $P$ is also the pressure throughout the gas. That is because in a reversible process the gas is in mechanical equilibrium with the surroundings, and the applicable equation of state can be used to determine the relationship between properties of the gas at each point along the process. For an ideal gas, that would be the ideal gas equation.

Bottom line: To fully interpret the $PV$ diagram you need information on whether the process(es) is reversible or irreversible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I know, thank you. If external pressure is put on axis than yes, every process can be shown. If we put internal pressure than we can't show irreversible proceses since internal pressure can't be determined by equation of state except for initial and final state.

Comment: @DarioMirić Exactly right. Just needed to know what you know.